# How do I get this website to render correctly in Internet Explorer 8 and below?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, web

I created a website last night that works in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera, but it isn't working in Internet Explorer

I tried creating conditional styling and html5.shiv in the head tags. My code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Flat Design</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="dist/html5shiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="PIE.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <style type="text/css">
                .wrap {
                    width: 980px;
                }
                .logo {
                    float: left;
                }
                .main-nav {
                    float: right;
                }
                .main {
                    width: 40.425531914894%;
                    height: 900px;
                    margin: 0;
                }
                .secondary {
                    width: 36.170212765957%;
                    height: 900px;
                    margin-left: 15px;
                }
                .extra {
                    display: block;
                    width: 23.404255319149%;
                    height: 900px;
                }
            </style>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
     <body>
<div class="wrap">
    <header class="main-header">
        <a class="logo" href="#"><h2>My Experience in Web Development</h2> </a>
        <nav class="main-nav">
            <a link href="#" class="hover">Home</a>
            <a link href="#" class="hover">About</a>
            <a link href="#" class="hover">Clients</a>
            <a link href="#" class="hover">News</a>
            <a link href="#" class="hover">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="content">

        <div class="main col">
            <h3>My candid experience in trying to find a job as a Web  Developer</h3>
            <p>It hasn't been a dull moment ever since I decided to switch careers to web development.</p>
            <p>I've taken up the arduous task of putting together a portfolio of several pieces of my best work. At the same time, I brushed up on my skillset by taking online courses at <a href="http://teamtreehouse.com">Team Treehouse</a> and several <a href="http://youtube.com">YouTube</a> tutorials, as well as utilized sites such as <a href="http://http://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>, <a href="http://sitepoint.com">SitePoint</a>, <a href="http://designmodo.com"/>Designmodo</a>,<a href="http://sixrevisions.com">Six Revisions</a>, etc.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="secondary col">
            <h3>Hitting the pavement for a job in web development.</h3>
            <p>In December of 2012, I decided to put my resume online to see what the job market was like in web development.</p>
            <p>A month later,I landed an assignment at Web 4 Purpose as a jr. front end web developer.I handled all of the CSS,HTML,Javascript coding from wireframes done in Adobe Photoshop or drawn.<br></p>
          </div>
           <div class="extra col">
            <h3>There's several web technologies.</h3>
            <p>Here's a short list of the several web technologies out there:</p>
            <ol>
                <li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp">HTML5</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_intro.asp">CSS3</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript">Javascript</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://jquery.com">JQuery</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com">Bootstrap</a>   </li>
                <li><a href="http://foundation.zurb.com">Foundation</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://angularjs.org">Angular.js</a>       </li>
            </ol>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="main-footer">
        <a href="http://twitter.com/MikeLegemah"><img src="img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" class="social-icon"></a>
        <a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="img/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" class="social-icon"></a>
        <a href="http://linkedin.com"><img src="img/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn" class="social-icon"></a>
        <a href="http://youtube.com"><img src="img/youtube.png" alt="YouTube" class="social-icon"></a>
        <a href="http://googleplus.com"><img src="img/googleplus.png" alt="Google Plus" class="social-icon"></a>
        <p>&copy; 2014 <a href="http://michaellegemah.com">michaellegemah.com</a></p>
    </footer>
  </div>
   </body>
    </html>
```

The CSS sheet is this:

```
                    * {
box-sizing: border-box;

   }
   body {
margin: 0;
padding-top: 25px;
background: #ECF0F1;
color: #FFF;
font: 1.3em/1.6 sans-serif; 

  }
  .wrap {
margin: auto;
width: 90%; 

  }
 .main-header {
background: #2C3E50;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-weight: 900;

 }
.logo, 
 .main-nav a {
display: inline-block;
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-weight: 900;

 }
 .main-nav a {
padding: 0 .75em;
border-right: 1px dotted;
color: #FFF;
font-size: .7em;
line-height: 1rem;
   }
  .main-nav a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
  }
 .main-nav a:last-child {
border-right: none;
 }
  .content, 
 .main-header {
overflow: hidden;
  }
  .col {
height: auto;
  }
 .main {
background: #3498DB;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 }

 h3 {
font-weight: 900;
 }
 li a, a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFF;
font-weight: 900;
  }
 .secondary {
background: #2ECC71;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  }
.extra {
display: none;
background: #C0392B;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  }
.main-footer {
background: #95A5A6;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.social-icon {
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 0 5px;
 border: none;
 }

 .main-header, 
 .main-footer, 
 .col {
margin-bottom: 15px;
padding: 2.15%;
border-radius: 5px;

 }










/* ==========================================================================
  Media Queries
 ========================================================================== */


/* Phones to Tablets */

 @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
.col {
    float: left;
}
.main {
    width: 65.957446808511%;
    height: 900px; 
}
.secondary {
    width: 31.914893617021%;
    height: 900px; 
}
.secondary,
.extra {
    margin-left: 2.127659574468%;
 }
}



/* Tablets to Desktop */

    @media only screen and (min-width: 769px) { 
.logo {
    float: left;
}
.main-nav {
    float: right;
}
.main {
    width: 40.425531914894%;
    height: 900px;
}
.secondary {
    height: 900px;
}

.extra {
    display: block;
    width: 23.404255319149%;
    height: 900px;
}
 }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {    
.wrap {
    width: 980px;
}
  }
```

Unfortunately, the result has been this: http://flatdesign.originexample.site90.com which looks fine in all browsers except IE

If anyone sees anything I might have overlooked, or if there's a better solution, please let me know thanks

Comment: Check your image, it looks like something went wrong

Comment: Can you also post the structure (tags) of your body?  html5shiv.js *should* take care of the main tags that IE8 doesn't recognize, but you could be using something unusual...

Comment: Thanks so much @AmeliaBR here is the link to the site: http://flatdesign.originexample.site90.com/ it works fine in every browser except IE

Answer (score 0):

Using the IE11 developer-tools emulator to mimick IE8, I'm seeing two main differences:

- no rounded corners;
- columns aren't floating side-by-side;

The border radius can't be fixed easily and doesn't really affect performance, so I hope you're okay with ignoring that.

The column floats are what's making it look really ugly, and thankfully that's easy to fix.

You're creating your columns with the following rule:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px){
  .col {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

The problem is the "only" keyword.  That keyword is designed to *prevent* browsers that don't recognize media queries from applying that style.  That includes IE8.  It reads it as a media query for a media type named "only"; it doesn't recognize that type, so it doesn't apply the style.  If you remove the keyword:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 481px){
  .col {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

Then IE8 reads that as `@media screen` *blah,blah,blah*.  It ignores the stuff it doesn't understand and applies the rule to all screens regardless of their width.

For IE8, that's probably okay, since nobody's using IE8 on a handheld device.  And if their screen is too narrow, that's okay since it just means the floated elements will end up one after another, the way they are without the floats.

It's possible that the change will also affect some older handheld devices that don't recognize `min-width` type media queries, but again, floats are pretty flexible.

One more thing: even when I added in a float property to your columns, the third column wasn't fitting in a row with the others.  Two possible culprits: either IE8 is automatically adding in padding or margins somewhere you're not expecting, or they are rounding lengths up to the next pixel and that's throwing off your addition.  A little bit of playing around with those settings should get them all side-by-side.  If you make your *last* column float *right* instead of left, you can get away with making the margins slightly smaller without ruining the rectangular lines of the design.